# regular expression for retrieving a particular string and number from URL

Tags: java, regex

I want to retrieve `IndiaRoute` and `919820673883` from this `URL`.

How can i do it using `Pattern` and a `Matcher`?

If there's some other way to do it then suggest me the snippet.

here is my URL

```
http://localhost:8080/IndiaRoute/servlet/SendSMPPClient?mno=919820673883&msg=xxx&sid=xxxx+&mt=0
```

thnks in advance

Comment: Give more examples of input strings and needed outputs. Regex can't be developed for a unique case. Get the string between the 3rd `/` and the 4th one, and the string between the first `mno=` and the next `&`?

Comment: What do you know, how `IndiaRoute` or your number differ from other strings/integers in the URL? To match only them, you need to find a distinction and describe it as a regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://.+/(.+?)/.+/.+\\?mno=(.+?)&");
    String s = "http://localhost:8080/IndiaRoute/servlet/SendSMPPClient?mno=919820673883&msg=xxx&sid=xxxx+&mt=0";
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

This will do the work until nothing in the url change.

Edit: Output

```
IndiaRoute
919820673883
```

Comment: thank you. 
the URL pattern is fixed..only the route mobile no will b changed